# Google app engine - multiple services - one database. Flask - sqlalchemy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to have multiple services on Google App Engine powered with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy and one MySQL database. The problem is that I have database version control (Flask-Migrate) and ORM definition (models.py) in one app.

The question is, how can I have right access to the database with the ORM from another service (another flask app)? Should I define the same models.py file for all this apps (share one copy)? I don't think this is the best solution

Thanks!